# boot AngularJS from command line like rails console

Tags: angularjs, command-line, read-eval-print-loop

I want to create a repl that loads my angular js app similar to rails console. How would I do this?

See:
http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html
http://derickbailey.com/2014/07/02/build-your-own-app-specific-repl-for-your-nodejs-app/

I have this:

```
var repl = require("repl");
var app = require('app');

// open the repl session
var replServer = repl.start({
  prompt: "> "
});
```

My angular JS file is:

```
// app/dist/app.js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages',
    'app.config',
    'app.controllers',
    'app.services'
  ]).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$mdThemingProvider', function($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .primaryPalette('grey', {
        'hue-2': '900'
      })
      .accentPalette('orange');

    $routeProvider.when('/foo', {templateUrl: 'partials/foo.html', controller: 'FooController'});

  }]);

})();
```

I want to include this and expose it to the repl.